# Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit Terminal Server Enterpriese crashes: RDP Service currently busy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

When this appears, no one log on to the server. This problem happens a few times in one week. We have the problem on all our 4 Terminal Servers. Microsoft has at this momment no solution for this problem. Thuis is a big problem in our organisation. I hope that one of the memmbers can help us.

Comment: Terminal Services have been renamed in 2008 R2; so I'm assuming you mean RD Session Host is installed. Do you have a License server? Are you using RD Connection Broker, Gateway, Web Access, VDI? TS Farm or Individual Servers; identical setups; hardware differences; recent updates or 3rd part software; when did it start doing this? You have opened a case with MS, or done Windows Updates, or contacted them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Is this to say that you have opened a support case with Microsoft?

What software is installed?

Do you have any other similar machines? (preferably matching in OS/Edition/Bitness as well as hardware)

-Waldo